Nature grammaticale du mot « que » dans le contexte de la construction présentative « c'est/ce n'est pas <>/à/de … que … »
Tiré de APHORISMES SUR LA SAGESSE DANS LA VIE, Arthur Schopenhauer, première traduction par J. A. Cantacuzène.

2° Quand on veut évaluer la condition d'un homme au point de vue de sa félicité, ce n'est
pas de ce qui le divertit, mais de ce qui l'attriste qu'on doit s'informer;

On trouve une construction similaire chez Rousseau, dans son Discours sur l’origine et les fondements de l’inégalité parmi les hommes, 1754

C’est de l’homme que j’ai à parler, et la question que j’examine m’apprend que je vais parler à des hommes;

Le TLFi rassemble les diverses possibilités dans un article.

(TLFi)
II. − Empl. pronom. Pronom non prédicatif, marque le genre de l'inanimé et assume toutes les fonctions régimes du substantif.
B − Que, pron. rel. avec antécédent
3. C'est ... que. [Tournure présentative: c'est l'antécédent qui assure la fonction gramm. régime, que étant un simple subordonnant]
a) [Régime dir.] C'est la personne que j'ai rencontrée.
b) [Régime indir.] C'est à cette personne que j'ai parlé.
c) [Régime circ.] C'est pour cela que je suis parti. C'est hier que je parlais.

Une forme  approximative plus complète de cette  construction peut s'écrire comme ci-dessous.

c'est/ce n'est pas  <>/à/de/de ce qui/de quoi/ … que …

Le TLFi parle de pronom  relatif et d'antécédent, puis dit que « que » est un simple subordonnant.

(Wikipédia) En grammaire, le pronom relatif est un pronom particulier qui se distingue des autres pronoms (personnels, démonstratifs, possessifs, etc.) par sa faculté d'introduire une nouvelle proposition (la proposition subordonnée relative).
Le CNRTL le définit comme « [mot] qui sert à rapporter, à joindre, au nom ou au pronom qu'il représente, et qui est son antécédent, une proposition subordonnée dite relative qui explique ou détermine l'antécédent ».

Tout ça pourrait finalement expliquer cette tournure, mais le pronom relatif « que » a la fonction de COD dans sa proposition ; dans la phrase de Schopenhauer, celle de Rousseau, et la seconde du TLFi il n'est pas question d'un verbe qui admette un COD, et dans la troisième du TLFi, c'est encore pire, le soi-disant antécédent est un cc du verbe, c'est un adverbe et non un nom. Il n'y a qu'un cas, la première phrase du TLFi (régime direct), où cette théorie soit valable : « que » est COD de « rencontrer » et « personne » est un antécédent valable.
Tout cela ressemble à mon avis à une horrible soupe grammaticale ; quelqu'un pourrait-il/elle tirer au clair cet embrouillamini ?  Est-ce vraiment possible que dans toutes ces phrases « que » soit un véritable pronom relatif ? (J'ai la conviction qu'on a là, dans le TLFi, une très grossière analyse de ce contexte grammatical ; à mon avis « que » est aussi la conjonction de subordination « que ».)

Quel est le problème exactement: déterminer l'antécédant de qu'(e), c'est à dire par quel(s) mot(s) le remplacer pour transformer " qu' on doit s'informer" en proposition indépendante? La seule solution est de remplacer par "non de ce qui le divertit, mais de ce qui l'attriste." Comment le problème s'analyse grammaticalment est pure tambouille de grammairiens, pas d'étudiant en pensée schopenhauerienne.

@FrançoisJurain Problème multiple : une forme pronominale qui ne correspond pas au régime du verbe,  donc des propositions relatives qui n'en sont pas, sonnent fausses à la lecture, et des antécédants qui tout d'un coup sont des adverbes ;je n'ai jamais entendu dire ou vu en écrit qu'un antécédant puisse être un adverbe, ça semble insensé.  L'article dans le  TLFi devrait vous rappeler que la traduction de Cantacuzène n'est qu'un exemple. Mais vous dites « de la tambouille » ? On est sensé examiner la grammaire sur le site FSE, justement, apprendre comment ne pas donner dans la tambouille.

Sans doute. N'empêche qu'il n'est pas possible de résoudre un problème sans l'énoncer. Si le problème est multiple, l'énoncer correctement nécessite de multiples questions sur fr.SE. Ou sur .SE.

Je ne vois pas trop de quel adverbe il s'agirait comme antécédent dans les exemples donnés?

@Frank Troisième exemple, TLFi, « hier »

@FrançoisJurain Le problème est énoncé correctement si on s'en tient aux principes grammaticaux connus ; évidemment, je peux développer, multiplier les exemple, mais la base de la question se conçoit bien tel que ma question est posée. Je ne l'ai posée d'ailleurs que pour m'assurer que je n'ai pas négligé la formule miracle qui rend tout parfait, et que quelqu'un aurait pu nous révéler (je crois que ça n'arrivera pas).

Ah oui. Aucun problème. C'est demain que je parlerai, c'est aujourd'hui que je parle, ... on peut dire ça toute la journée.

@LPH La "formule miracle" qui t'as déjà été donnée est qu'il n'y a pas de problème et qu'on a affaire à un pronom relatif, et c'est tout.

@Frank Il ne s'agit pas sur le présent site de justifier de la grammaire en disant « on peut dire ça toute la journée » ; les grammairiens ne font pas ça ; même les étudiants les plus innocents vont vous dire que vous essayez de les prendre pour des idiots

@FrançoisJurain De toute façon, posé d'une manière ou d'une autre, ça ne sert à rien, ce n'est même pas lu (« Où est l'adverbe ?»).

Voici un problème énoncé clairement: J'affirme que les deux phrases suivantes sont deux exemples d'emploi d'un même mot, marqué en gras, dans une même fonction grammaticale. De quelle nature est ce mot et quelle est sa fonction? "Quand on veut évaluer la condition d'un homme au point de vue de sa félicité, ce n'est pas de ce qui le divertit, mais de ce qui l'attriste qu' on doit s'informer" et "C’est de l’homme que j’ai à parler, et la question que j’examine m’apprend que je vais parler à des hommes". Si ce n'est pas l'essence du post, VTC jusqu'à clarification.

On peut aussi dire: c'est d'aujourd'hui que je parle, c'est d'hier que je parle, c'est de demain que je parlerai (sens différent avec ce petit d'). L'adverbe semble être un peu nominalisé.

@Frank Vous ne m'apprenez rien ; ce qui est en question c'est la grammaire, c'est à dire la structure dans laquelle s'inscrivent des énoncés de cette sorte.

@FrançoisJurain Non seulement ce que vous présentez est en question, et en fait ce ne sont que des cas bien reconnus, mais plus essentiellement une justification par le TLFi ; si j'avais cru que le TLFi soit dans le vrai je n'aurais pas posé de question ; cependant je ne reconnais pas leur identification de « que » en tant que pronom comme valide, sauf dans le premier exemple où « que » a un antécédent normal et est bien le COD du verbe. // Non, pas un même mot dans ma question, mais une même forme. « Que » pronom et « que » conjonction sont des mots différents.

On pourrait remplacer ce que par:

c'est de l'homme dont je dois parler

et ce dont, dans la même position et le même rôle que ce que, serait un pronom relatif. TLFi recense certains cas où Le pron. rel. peut introduire des subordonnées juxtaposées et/ou coordonnées. Mais ici, il me semble qu'il s'agit bien d'un pronom relatif sans grand problème, comme le suggère ce remplacement possible par dont.

Ce n'est pas ce qu'on vous demande, mais pas du tout alors.

@LPH "Nature grammaticale du mot « que »...", "Est-ce vraiment possible que dans toutes ces phrases « que » soit un véritable pronom relatif?" - est-ce là la question?

Oui, est-ce que par miracle on peut encore appeler « que » un pronom relatif ? D'où sort cette théorie ? Les deux cas que je cite d'abord ne sont pas des cas isolés, on s'en rend compte à la lecture de l'article du TLFi. Personnellement, je n'arrive pas à y croire, pas c'est trop énorme.

@LPH Que n'overréactes tu pas ! Que est bien un pronom relatif qui remplace de l'homme puisqu'on peut dire Je dois parler de l'homme.  Rien que de naturel ici, pas de miracle. Que n'arrives-tu pas à croire ?

@jlliagre Pourquoi vous arrêtez vous sur la partie négligeable qui confirme confortablement les assertions du TLFi et ignorez tout le reste, bien plus important en quantité, qui l'infirme affreusement ? Ça saute aux yeux ! Vous croyez pouvoir faire l'autruche ?

@LPH Je ne fais pas l'autruche, les autruches non plus d'ailleurs mais je m'égare. Qu'est-ce qui devrait me sauter aux yeux ? Quels que ne  sont pas des pronoms relatifs pour toi (si c'est bien le problème), et pourquoi ? Comment les qualifierais-tu alors ?

@jlliagre 1/ Le pronom relatif qui convient pour les verbes intransitifs « parler à », « expliquer à », etc. c'est « à qui » : « C'est la personne à qui j'ai parlé. ». Dans « C'est à cette personne que j'ai parlé.  », « que » est le pronom COD, et donc la syntaxe dans la proposition subordonnée « que j'ai parlé » est complètement fausse. Les pronoms relatifs sont compris comme étant des éléments grammaticaux qui rendent dans la proposition la relation grammaticale qui existe entre un verbe et le mot remplacé.  2/  où est-il dit que l'antécédent d'un relatif peut être un adverbe ? 3/ …

Tu peux dire autant que tu veux que C'est à cette personne que j'ai parlé est "faux", mais tout le monde continuera à le dire et à l'écrire quand même (car ce n'est pas faux, évidemment). Aucun problème.

C'est à vous que je parle, ma sœur. Molière, Les Femmes sçavantes.

@jlliagre Eh bien, j'aurais à dire que Molière, qui après tout n'était pas concerné par la grammaire mais le théâtre n'avait pas une notion exacte de ce qu'est un pronom relatif ; mais non, c'est plutôt que Molière n'avait pas à se soucier de ce qu'il écrivait puisque c'était dit et redit dans son monde ; on ne va pas demander des explications de grammaire à Molière : le fait que Molière ait utilisé cette forme ne nous dit pas que « que » est un pronom relatif. Encore  une fois vous ne démontrez rien. « Que »,  pas un pronom relatif,  pas utilisé selon  manière acceptée de mise en relation.

Mais qui est concerné par la grammaire ? La grammaire observe et cherche à expliquer, à trouver une logique. Elle n'a pas (ou plus?) la prétention de dicter à qui que ce soit ce qu'il peut ou ne peut pas dire. Le langage n'est pas un produit fini construit sur plan, il a existé des centaines de milliers d'années avant que n'apparaissent les premiers grammairiens.

Oui la grammaire arrive après Molière, pour ainsi dire - elle observe ce que Molière écrit en français, et prend note. Mais c'est Molière qui "a raison", par définition. D'ailleurs, toutes les références, TLFi, Grevisse, ... sont remplies d'exemples d'auteurs français ...


quelqu'un pourrait-il/elle tirer au clair cet embrouillamini ?

Arthur Schopenhauer, German philosopher, wrote some various notes (in German) about the French relative pronoun que, and his notes were translated into French by J.A.  Cantacuzène, Romanian politician & scholar.
In that excerpt of his notes, Arthur identifies que in what he calls the Tournure présentative and in function of Que, pron. rel. avec antécédent, he says that the usage with que is « Pronom non prédicatif, marque le genre de l'inanimé et assume toutes les fonctions régimes du substantif. »
Many people explain “avoir agreement” as with “the direct object“ before que relative pronoun.  Arthur stated “the direct object“ before que as the antécédent.
Lingolia (Germany) also calls que a relative pronoun in the formation of “avoir agreement.”
You, and many others, say that specific que in “avoir agreement” is a COD.
I say that specific que in “avoir agreement” is an adjective, and more precisely it’s an adjective locution.

Est-ce vraiment possible que dans toutes ces phrases « que » soit un véritable pronom relatif ?

According to Arthur, yes, in those specific sentence examples for that specific excerpt.

… à mon avis « que » est aussi la conjonction de subordination « que ».)

You are correct, though que isn’t a conjunction with Arthur’s sentence examples in the excerpt.
HOWEVER, in other syntax structures …
que has 5 types of conjunctions, 5 types of adverbs, 2 types of relative pronouns, 1 imperative, and 1 adjective locution.

Hmmm... Kézako^2

Quelqu'un parle enfin de grammaire, même si les références sont phantasmagoriques.

Double quotes (« ») mean you're quoting exact words from s.o. So what I gather from what you write is that « Pronom non prédicatif [...]  régimes du substantif. » is a sentence you have found in Cantacuzène's translation of Schopenhauer's "notes  about the French relative pronoun que". Could we please have a more precise reference as to these notes (published where ? when ?) available online  (Much  of S's work is since it's no longer under copyright).

I expect you are aware that the translations of Schopenhauer's works into French by Cantacuzène, whose L1 was neither French nor German, is criticised by specialists. So trying to explain grammar through what he wrote cannot be very convincing.

@None   I completely agree with you.  Nowhere did I suggest that Arthur's notes were taken for grammatical truth.  In fact, I clearly stated he wrote his various notes in German and then they were translated by a Romanian scholar.  I also gave other various opinions that also aren't necessarily grammatical truths of the SAME structure. So it's a topic with some controversy, and I was only answering the questions asked by the OP.   I'm not sure why the downvotes, although I certainly was expecting that from those who don't understand the difference.

The downvotes are probably because what you say is rather unclear, it's difficult to follow your reasoning. As far as I'm concerned when I read your 1st & 2nd § I expect to have some justification.  "Arthur Schopenhauer, German philosopher, wrote some various notes (in German) about the French relative pronoun que," : have you read those notes about que and are you quoting from there? When I read your 2nd §  all I see  is a sentence form the TLF...

@None The quoted sentence in my answer is from the OP’s reference of it.   Is it too much presumption for me to think that anyone reading my answer has first read the OP’s question?   I don’t believe my answer was unclear, based on what the OP asked.  Other than that, are you saying that a full citation is needed for the quote in my answer that was directly from the OP’s question?

“have you read those notes about que and are you quoting from there?”    Hmmm, the OP’s question included the notes about que, along with her own statements including where the quote was quoted from.  If I’m including a quote in my answer that was directly from the post that I’m replying to, are you saying that quote requires a citation?

I'm sorry to say you misread the question. The question does not include  "A.S 's [...] notes (in German) about the French relative pronoun que, and his notes were translated into French by J.A. Cantacuzène" ( his notes means A.S.'s notes). // Your use of he/his all along the 1st & 2nd § refers to A.S.  "Arthur identifies que in what he calls the Tournure [...] he says that the usage ...": "he" in your sentence cannot be any other than the last male person named, i.e. A.S.

//  3rd §: "Arthur stated “the direct object“ before que as the antécédent : you write "Arthur stated...", not the OP, so I'm asking you:  where did "Arthur" say that? // When s.o. tells you what you write is unclear (and I'm not the only one), maybe you could consider improving it instead of hinting they did not read the question first.
